# DateTimePicker Bootstrap hiding input field on blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So, I'm using [this](http://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) [Bootstrap DateTimePicker] plugin to allow the user to pick a date and time.  The plugin works fine, except for one small problem, whenever the user clicks away or blurs the calendar box, the box itself and the input element disappear!

I have looked in the css and js files to find something that might lead me in the right path (focus, blur, etc), but I have not had any luck.

I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.  Thank you!

[image: Before blurring off]

[image: After blur]

This is the HTML creating the element:

```
<div id="eventstartdate" class="input-append date"><input type="text" data-format="dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss" /><span class="add-on">
<i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i></span></div>

<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#eventstartdate').datetimepicker({

            language: 'en',
            pick12HourFormat: true,
            format: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss',
            maskInput: true

        });

    });
    </script>
```

Comment: What does your code look like? The example on the link you provided does not disappear so must be something in your code.

Comment: Please post your html and js code,  or better create a fiddle

Comment: I will. Sorry about that. And the problem with a jfiddle is that I'm using MVC and the html is being created somewhere else other than the View (a Html helper), it must be something conflicting with another file (plugin or javascript) since whenever I isolate this particular plugin, it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I could not find the correct manner to do this, so for the moment being all I did was unbind the hiding of the div like this:

```
$('#eventstartdate').on('hide', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); });
```

This works until I find a better solution :/

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened to me and  at last it turns out that , prototype.js was the culprit . The reason is that prototype has these methods called hide and show, that it attaches to every dom element and when bootstrap triggers  methods with same name on its components(like dialog,dropdowns etc..), respective method of prototype acts on the dom element itself causing it to hide . As a workaround you can use below code after loading prototype.

```
if (Prototype.BrowserFeatures.ElementExtensions) {
var disablePrototypeJS = function (method, pluginsToDisable) {
        var handler = function (event) {
            event.target[method] = undefined;
            setTimeout(function () {
                delete event.target[method];
            }, 0);
        };
        pluginsToDisable.each(function (plugin) { 
            jQuery(window).on(method + '.bs.' + plugin, handler);
        });
    },
    pluginsToDisable = ['collapse', 'dropdown', 'modal', 'tooltip', 'popover', 'tab','datepicker'];
disablePrototypeJS('show', pluginsToDisable);
disablePrototypeJS('hide', pluginsToDisable);  }
```